# cannot continue the application is improperly formatted

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment

i'm having a big issue installing a published vb.net software on another machine  , it works properly on my pc (where i developed the software )

but when i try to install  it on other machines  it throws this error message

"cannot continue .the application is improperly formatted.contact the application vendor ...etc "

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18408
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/wbc/Videos/Walido%20GYM.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Walido GYM.application, Version=1.0.0.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09750bed798d4b36, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\wbc\Videos\Walido GYM.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/wbc/Videos/Application%20Files/Walido%20GYM_1_0_0_7/Walido%20GYM.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        + Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [23/12/2016 18:24:16] : Activation of C:\Users\wbc\Videos\Walido GYM.application has started.
    * [23/12/2016 18:24:17] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [23/12/2016 18:24:17] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [23/12/2016 18:24:17] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/wbc/Videos/Application%20Files/Walido%20GYM_1_0_0_7/Walido%20GYM.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

edited:
after  using MyApplication_UnhandledException  to throw out infos about problem

i got this message :

```
    Prerequisite check for system component SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP2 (x86) failed with the following error message:
"This version of SQL Server 2005 Express Edition (x86) is not supported for the current processor architecture."


See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\rose\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDE833.tmp\install.log' for more information.
```

i downloaded another version of sql server 2005 express and installed it then tried again  another error message popped out  says :

```
Prerequisite check for system component SQL Server 2008 Express failed with the following error message:
"The instance of SQL Server 2005 Express named 'SQLEXPRESS' contains components that are not included in SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1. SQL Server 2008 Express SP1 cannot upgrade this instance. Please use SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services instead."


See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\rose\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDDE9B.tmp\install.log' for more information.
```

i went to project proprieties and unchecked  sql server  Prerequisites 
published my project  (this time no setup )

when i clicked on (exe) file  nothing  comes out 
also when i click on clickonce depl application manifest file  another error comes out

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18408
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///E:/555/Application%20Files/Walido%20GYM_1_0_0_15/Walido%20GYM.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Walido GYM.application, Version=1.0.0.15, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///E:/555/Application Files/Walido GYM_1_0_0_15/Application Files/Walido GYM_1_0_0_15/Walido GYM.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.exe.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [24/12/2016 15:11:02] : Activation of E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.application has started.
    * [24/12/2016 15:11:02] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [24/12/2016 15:11:02] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [24/12/2016 15:11:02] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///E:/555/Application Files/Walido GYM_1_0_0_15/Application Files/Walido GYM_1_0_0_15/Walido GYM.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'E:\555\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Application Files\Walido GYM_1_0_0_15\Walido GYM.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: Make sure the target computer has the same .NET Framework version that your application uses. Second option, try this similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619037/3740093

Comment: i installed same .NET framework version 4.5.1  but still same problem

Comment: here is also what i get when i click on .exe  found on application files folder 
CLR20r3
   01: walido gym.exe
   02: 1.0.0.0
   03: 585d76fc
   04: Microsoft.VisualBasic
   05: 11.0.50938.18408
   06: 52313bc9
   07: 88
   08: 8
   09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
      : 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
      : 1036
     1: 0a9e
     2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
     3: 0a9e
     4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: Are you using Visual Basic PowerPacks? Make sure that is installed on the target computer too. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10).

Comment: it's installed in both machines but still have same problem

Comment: btw i'm also using devexpress ui  might be the one causes this problem ??

Comment: You can try making sure it exists on the target machine, but I don't think DevExpress is the problem. According to the error you posted it has to do with the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. Please try [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134471/3740093) too.

Comment: If that doesn't work either, go to [**the application events**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2bys999(v=vs.100).aspx) and add an event handler to `UnhandledException` via the event list on the top right of the code editor. Then inside the event handler type `My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(e.Exception.ToString())`. Doing so will put the error message in the clipboard so that you'll be able to paste it anywhere via right-click -> Paste or by pressing `CTRL + V`. -- Please edit your question and paste the error message in there.

Comment: Prerequisite check for system component SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP2 (x86) failed with the following error message:
"This version of SQL Server 2005 Express Edition (x86) is not supported for the current processor architecture."


See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\rose\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDE833.tmp\install.log' for more information.

Comment: See this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/737f19ba-51da-4834-9be7-010a1f45846f/sql-server-2005-express-edition-is-not-supported?forum=netfx64bit

Comment: i updated my question  ....... still nothing working

Comment: Check these two: [\[ 1 \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682047/including-a-named-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express-with-my-application) [\[ 2 \]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2009/06/15/how-should-i-install-sql-server-2008/), perhaps they can give you some more information.

Comment: Here are a few more: [\[ 1 \]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3606268c-ed79-4fec-a957-dc5d2b074472/getting-error-for-install-of-prerequisite-components-in-64-bit-operating-system?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade) [\[ 2 \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20236674/3740093) [\[ 3 \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585862/already-installed-sql-server-how-to-run-click-one-application-with-two-version).